# How do I convert my materials to textures for Unity?

Tags: texturing, materials, export, unity

I'm very new to blender so either a step-by-step process or laymen's terms would be much appreciated.

I am trying to export a model of a wooden plank I made, into unity with the textures as well.

Currently, it is textureless in Unity:

[image: Image of Unity with a textureless rectangle]

In blender, I've tried exporting as a .FBX file and simply putting the project file in Unity with the same result.

I believe I need to bake the image and convert the material to a texture.
I have a cube with these shaders added:

[image: 3d model of a wooden plank]

When I try to bake the image it says "No active image found in material "Material" (0) for object "Cube"

The online tutorials I've found are either too vague or not what I'm looking for.
So I still may be incorrect in the process I should follow.
Any help would mean a lot to me and If I've been too vague I'll add more detail to this post ASAP!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: You have to bake out your node based shaders into texture maps